# Cannot bind knockoutjs with mvc view

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, twitter-bootstrap, knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

I am new in knockoutjs, i am trying to bind the view, but cannot. Data from server is fetching fine, ajax is working fine, but not binding issue.

Here is my js code:

```
var UserViewModel = function () {
var self = this;
//Declare observable which will be bind with UI 
self.Id = ko.observable("0");
self.FirstName = ko.observable("");
self.LastName = ko.observable("");

//The Object which stored data entered in the observables
var UserData = {
    Id: self.Id || 0,
    FirstName: self.FirstName || '',
    LastName: self.LastName || ''
   };

//Declare an ObservableArray for Storing the JSON Response
self.Users = ko.observableArray([]);

GetUser(12); //This is server side method.

function GetUser(userId) {
    //Ajax Call Get All Employee Records
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/api/Users/" + userId,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (response) {
            //alert("success");
            UserData = response.data.UserData;
            alert(UserData.FirstName); //This is showing me correct name.
            self.Users(response.data.UserData); //Put the response in ObservableArray
        },
        error: function (error) {
            alert(error.status);
        }
    });
    //Ends Here
}
}

ko.applyBindings(new UserViewModel());
```

Here is my view:

```
  <form class="form-horizontal" data-bind="with: UserData">
                           <div class="row">
                               <div class="control-group">
                                   <label class="control-label">First Name</label>
                                   <label class="control-label" data-bind="text: FirstName"></label>
                               </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="row">
                              <div class="control-group">
                                   <label class="control-label">Last Name</label>
                                   <input type="text" placeholder="Last Name" data-bind="value: LastName">
                               </div>
                            </div>
```

Comment: What is the error you are receiving?

Comment: no error, it is not binding values.

Comment: Set up a fiddle then it is probably just a syntax error

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you are trying to two-way data-bind against a non-observable property, so when you update it it isn't notifying the UI.  Make your user an observable and set it to an instance of an object or create a model to derive your properties from.

```
function userModel(user) {
    var self = this;
    self.Id = ko.observable(user.Id);
    self.FirstName = ko.observable(user.FirstName);
    self.LastName = ko.observable(user.LastName);
}


var viewModel = function () {
    var self = this;    
    //The Object which stored data entered in the observables
    var UserData = ko.observable();
    GetUser(12);
    function GetUser(userId) {
        //Ajax Call Get All Employee Records
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "/api/Users/" + userId,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (response) {
                //alert("success");
                UserData(new userModel(response.data.UserData));
                alert(UserData().FirstName()); //This is showing me correct name.
                self.Users.push(UserData()); //Put the response in ObservableArray
            },
            error: function (error) {
                alert(error.status);
            }
        });
    }
}
ko.applyBindings(new viewModel());
```

Comment: It should be ko.applyBindings(new viewModel());? or i am wrong?

Comment: That's correct I was copying and pasting some of the above code let me update

Comment: Gives me this error :(  "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'push' of undefined"

Comment: Because self.Users is not defined in my code above.  Add it like you had before self.Users = ko.observableArray();  You need to read up on the docs

Comment: added line self.Users = ko.observableArray([]); removed error, but still not binding :(

Answer (score -1):

Here, take from the following fiddle ::
http://jsfiddle.net/9ZCBw/

where you have a container model which owns the collection of users and has the function (ajax stripped for usability under fiddle)

```
function ViewModel () {
    var self = this;
    self.Users = ko.observableArray();

    self.GetUser = function (userId) {
        var UserData = {
            Id: userId,
            FirstName: 'Bob',
            LastName: 'Ross'
        };
        self.Users.push(new UserModel(UserData));
    }
}
```

Here, you have instances of Users which can then be bound to you model...as also shown.

Comment: -1 for using my code to create an answer instead of offering a suggested edit to it

Comment: actually, I was off making my own fiddle and didn't see your code until after I published my answer...funny how good minds can think alike.

Comment: besides, your model doesn't have an observable array of users...you are suggesting the 'push'-ing of a new user to an observable array that has yet to be declared. [self.Users]

Comment: As referenced in the comments, the OP is responsible for incorporating the code changes into their existing code base including knowing that he still needs an observableArray to push a new value into it...